# How to Disable Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page? messagebox in onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onbeforeunload

I use the following onbeforeunload  for call when the browser close.I get the alert properly also i get the **Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?** message box automatically generate by the web browser.But I no need to display that message box when the browser is close.How to disable **Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?** messagebox?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) 
{

           if($.browser.msie)
           {
               alert('Test');
               return false;
            }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't return a value, ie:

```
return;
```

Or, since the condition is a constant factor:

```
if($.browser.msie) {
    window.onload = function() {alert('Test');};
} else {
    window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
        return 'Are you sure to quit?'; // <-- Message is displayed in *some* browsers
    }
}
```

If you're trying to implement a method which prevents the user from navigating away: **There is no way to achieve that**. It'd be a horrible experience to not be able to leave a page.

Comment: @user Explain "Not working". If I wanted X to do Y, but you want X to do X, then we're not on the same line.