# Why is Oracle ADF insisting that I have dependent dialogs open?

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I am creating a prototype web app using Oracle Weblogic/ADF. I am using JDeveloper 11.1.1.6.0.

I have a basic application with one entity object and one view object. One of the requirements I is that once data is changed it must be digitally signed. I am using a applet/servlet based solution to get this done.

Once a user decides to edit an entry in the table they are taken to a page that shows a two-column form layout. On this page is a button that, when clicked, brings up an ADF dialog window. On this page there is a button called "Sign". Once the user clicks the "Sign" button some JavaScript executes that communicates with the embedded applet. This embedded applet in turn communicates with a servlet and returns a string representing a signature. This process is task-flow based.

The issue I am having is that for SOME users (IE 8, Win 7 Enterprise) once they click the "Sign" button on the popup they are shown the following popup:

[image]

If they click "OK", the page reloads and when they click "Sign" again the process repeats resulting in a loop. Initially I thought the alert was coming from IE, but upon further research it seems that the alert is coming from ADF. I have NO idea WHY they are getting this message as there are NO dependent dialogs. I have tried setting the "uncommitted data warning" to off for the document but I still get the same popup. Also the message ONLY appears for SOME users running IE 8 on top of Windows 7.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to get this popup to stop and/or WHY it is happening?
ANY help would be greatly appreciated as I am stumped.

Thanks.

Comment: Somewhere a piece of Javascript has gone awry in your application. Have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152780/how-to-disable-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-messagebox

Comment: That's what I am not understanding though. Why would some users get this message and others not? Same IE and OS versions.

Comment: Different versions of certain Browsers is probably interpreting the js differently. Maybe, that's the cause. But I would concentrate on the java script to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

disable the uncommitted data warning property on af:document

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_document.html

Frank

Comment: I did. Still does not work. I am not getting an uncommitted data notification, I am getting a dependent dialog notification.